# How do i start scanning from the second row of my CSV data to linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list, java.util.scanner

So my CSV file contains something like in excel

```
     speed period warning pair
 1     26     1      1      1
 2     26     1      1      1
 3     26     1      1      1
 4     26     1      1      1
```

In my scanner file i have

```
public class scanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // open file input stream
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "amis.csv"));

        // read file line by line
        String line = null;
        Scanner scanner = null;
        int index = 0;
        List<amis> empList = new ArrayList<>();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            amis emp = new amis();
            scanner = new Scanner(line);
            scanner.useDelimiter(",");
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String data = scanner.next();
                if (index == 0) {
                    emp.setId(data);
                } else if (index == 4) {
                    emp.setPair(data);
                } else if (index == 3) {
                    emp.setWarning(data);
                } else if (index == 2) {
                    emp.setPeriod(data);
                }else if (index == 1) {
                    emp.setSpeed(data);
                }else {
                    System.out.println("invalid data::" + data);
                }
                index++;
            }
            index = 0;
            empList.add(emp);
        }

        //close reader
        reader.close();

        System.out.println(empList);

    }
```

But the output of my linked list will show

ID=""::Pair="pair"::Warning="warning"::Period="period"::Speed="speed",

ID="1"::Pair=1::Warning=1::Period=1::Speed=26,

ID="2"::Pair=1::Warning=1::Period=1::Speed=26,

ID="3"::Pair=1::Warning=1::Period=1::Speed=26,

ID="4"::Pair=1::Warning=1::Period=1::Speed=26,

How to i just start from the second row.

Comment: Call `reader.readLine();` before your `while` loop.

Comment: Do you really have to read csv file like that? If no use [commons-csv](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/). If yes, try to use recommended file-reading manner: [Java try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks! That solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call `scanner.nextLine` before while loop, e.g.:

```
String headers = reader.nextLine();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
```

This is what the documentation says:

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the
>   beginning of the next line.

So, in the while loop, you will get all the lines from second line.